# how to install java8 in ubuntu instance using packer provisioner?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, packer

Trying to build an AMI using packer from an base ami available online (preferably ubuntu 12.04 precise). Looking for provisioner definition for java 8 installation. I have coupled multiple installations and executed it has went through well. But, java8 using ppa is not happening with following commands in the definition. With chef its happening without any troubles, but i want to do it with packer provisioners.

```
"sudo apt-get install python-software-properties",
"sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java",
"sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer".
```

Other alternatives i tried :

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Reference:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/445536/unable-to-locate-package-add-apt-repository-error

Please do help me with provisioner definitions if u found any successful implementations.

error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/xyzqwerty# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: WHY is it not happening? What is the error?

Comment: unable to locate the repository... i tried checking on multiple forums and other references..couldnt find a proper working model.

Comment: Post the error in your question.

Comment: edited with error snippet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common",
"sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java",
"sudo apt-get update",
"echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections",
"echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections",
"sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer",
"sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default",
```

[got it here](https://github.com/cloudspace-devops/packer-shell-scripts/blob/master/java.sh)